# Database design for form with many fields

Tags: sql-server, database-design

A form contains 30-40 different fields (some more might be added in the future, so this has to be possible) and I need to find a good data structure to save them in a database (MS SQL Server). These fields can have different types like checkboxes (true/false), selects (1 to x possible values to choose from) and text fields. Every form can be identified by a composite key of the operation number (string) and a revision (int).

Here is an example, just think of some more of these types of fields:
[Example form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1SNK.png)

I would try it this way:

```
- table form
  - operation_number nvarchar(255) PK
  - revision int PK
  - created_at datetime
------------------------------------------------
This will be used for all true/false checkboxes:
- table checkbox_option
  - id int PK
  - form_operation_number nvarchar(255) FK (for form.operation_number)
  - form_revision int FK (for form.revision)
  - value bit
------------------------------------------------
This will be used for all text fields (see "Locations" and "Additional comments" in the example):
- table text_option
  - id int PK
  - form_operation_number nvarchar(255) FK (for form.operation_number)
  - form_revision int FK (for form.revision)
  - value varchar(max)
------------------------------------------------
This will be used for all selects:
- table select_option_name
  - id int PK
  - form_operation_number nvarchar(255) FK (for form.operation_number)
  - form_revision int FK (for form.revision)
  - name string (the text for the label, like "color" in the example)
------------------------------------------------
- table select_option_junction
  - select_option_name_id int PK FK (for select_option_name.id)
  - select_option_values_id int PK FK (for select_option_value.id)
------------------------------------------------
Table for all the options of a select field:
- table select_option_values
  - id int PK
  - value nvarchar(255)
```

Does this seem like a good design or have I forgotten something important? Maybe you have a better idea? Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to design a storage schema for dynamic form generation, either way "Is this a good design" is highly subjective. If you can justify the schema and it works for your application, then accept it and move on. I would do it slightly differently with less tables, but expediency is the key here for you. Do what works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> id int PK

You will see much advice encouraging this design choice.  I recommend against.

Begin by going a little deeper than you have so far.  Determine the *domain* of each column.  Decide on its relationship to the form.  Any column for which more than one value may appear in the form (as, say, order items in sales order) goes in another table, related to the form by a foreign key.

Figure out what values in any row uniquely identify the row, i.e., distinguish it from all others.  That is a *natural key*. By using natural keys, you're forced to understand the cardinality of the data, and you enable the DBMS to enforce it.

Your color column, for example, would have a table of all possible colors, a *domain table*.  You could use the color name as the primary key, because no two colors have the same name.  Then, in your form table, you have a color column with a foreign key to the colors table. If the user somehow tried to insert a form-table row with a color not in the colors table, the DBMS would reject it with a foreign key violation.

If OTOH you choose to use **id int PK** as the primary key for your colors table, nothing prevents, say, "blue" from appearing twice in the table, perhaps ids 7 and 17.  To prevent that, you have to do the same analysis needed to define natural keys.  Adding the surrogate **id** key just creates more work.

The natural key also is easier to work with.
With an **id** primary key, your form-table has only an opaque number in the color column.  If you use the natural key, you'll see "red" instead of maybe 11.

Someone will warn you that natural keys can change.  A person's name, for example, may change.  That's usually evidence that the column isn't actually a natural key.  More important: if you lack a solid example in the data, any design effort to compensate for the possibility that stable data will change will likely prove insufficient (and wrong) when that change does arrive, if it does.

There are cases where no natural key exists, or seems not to.  Sometimes, as with grocery items or stocks, the indistinguishable items can be accounted for by counting them in a quantity column. For rows that change over time (and are kept over time), adding a date to the key often works.

Occasionally, though, you're adding something completely new to the database, something that no human being can be bothered to name.  *That's* when you'll need to invent a key.